# In Enumitem, how to keep with item with a subitem in the same page?

Tags: page-breaking, enumitem

I think the title says it all.
If I have a page that ends like:

```
15 something
15.1 should be in the same page as 15. not in the next.
```

The same should be done for other deeper levels:

```
15.2 and
15.2.1 for example
```

My current setup is:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep, topsep=10pt, partopsep=20pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label*=\enspace \arabic*.,before=\normalfont\mdseries,after=\normalfont,leftmargin=1.3em\Large}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape\normalsize,after=\normalfont}
\setlist[enumerate,3]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape,after=\normalfont}
```

\setlist[enumerate,4]{label*=\arabic*.,before=\normalfont\upshape,after=\normalfont}

Comment: You now have `penalties` that can be set with `enumitem`. See  § 2.5, p. 11 of the last version of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Adding

```
\setlist[enumerate,2]{beginpenalty=10000}
```

to the preamble will do that (see section 3.5 "Penalties" in the `enumitem` manual).